# How to store a list of smart pointers inside a c++ class?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I have a class `Node` that must have a list of its input `Edge`'s. These input `Edge`'s, however, are not meant to be modified by `Node`, only accessed. I have been advised to use smart pointers for that matter, like this:

```
class Node
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Edge>> inEdges;
//...
public:
    void inline AddEdge(std::unique_ptr<Edge>& edge) // could be const here too
    {
        this->inEdges.push_back(edge);
    }
//...
}
```

So in the runtime I can create a list of nodes and edges and assign edges to each node:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Nodes>> nodes;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Edges>> edges;
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(0, 0.5, 0.0));
    nodes.push_back(std::make_unique<Node>(1, 0.5, 0.0));
    edges.push_back(std::make_unique<Edge>(*nodes[0], *nodes[1], 1.0));
    nodes[1]->AddEdge(edges[0]);
}
```

The compiler gives the error

> Error 1   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 593 1   sirs

It used to work with raw pointers inside the `Node`'s `std::vector<Edge*>`, given that the signature of `AddEdge` would be `void AddEdge(Edge& edge);`, pushing back `&edge` inside the vector.

What is wrong with my code? How should I proceed to correct it? Given that `std::vector` cannot store references, because these are not assignable.

PS: I do not want to transfer ownership of the pointers to the `Node` objects...

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` can be moved, but not copied. Your `AddEdge` should take it by value, and pass it further with `std::move`

Comment: Does the `Node` own the edges? If no, use raw pointers (or `std::reference_wrapper`). If yes: What's wrong with plain `std::vector<Edge>` instead?

Comment: But I do not want to transfer ownership of the pointer

Comment: `Edge`'s have their own dynamics... Each `Node` is able to get only the output signal of each `Edge`... So a `Node` does not own the `Edge`'s

Comment: @Girardi So why are you using `std::unique_ptr` then?

Comment: @Rakete1111 well, I came up to `std::unique_ptr` through reading online... I am quite new to C++

Comment: Should it be `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @Girardi Well, the object that owns the pointer has the `std::unique_ptr` object. If some other object wants to use it, (which would be non-owning), just pass the raw pointer.

Comment: If I pass the raw pointer to `Node` and then delete the `unique_ptr`, what happens to the raw pointer?

Comment: @Girardi *"Should it be `std::shared_ptr`?"* No. Smart pointers imply ownership. To just observe without owning use raw pointers and references. Use the latter (possibly via `std::reference_wrapper` if the pointers must never be 0.

Answer (score 8):

You should only *move* instances of `std::unique_ptr` in order to get them in a `std::vector`. Otherwise you need `std::shared_ptr`.

```
class Node
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Edge>> inEdges;
//...
public:
    void AddEdge(std::unique_ptr<Edge>&& edge)
    {
        inEdges.push_back(std::move(edge));
    }
//...
}
```

I've changed `AddEdge` to take an r-value reference in order to support move semantics properly.

To call:

```
node.AddEdge(std::move(edge));
```

Or:

```
node.AddEdge(std::make_unique<Edge>(/*args*/));
```

As an aside. If you do find you're passing `std::unique_ptr` by reference, it might be a sign you should be using `std::shared_ptr`.

Also, `inline` is redundant on methods declared inside a class.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector::push_back` copies its argument, and `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied, it can only be moved.

You'll have to move the passed `std::unique_ptr`:

```
void inline AddEdge(std::unique_ptr<Edge> edge)
{
    this->inEdges.push_back(std::move(edge));
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
nodes[1]->AddEdge(std::move(edges[0]));
```

---

Also, `inEdges` doesn't have to be a vector for `std::unique_ptr`, as they should be non-owning. A `std::unique_ptr` implies ownership, but as you said, `Node` doesn't own the `Edge`s.

Use `std::vector<Edge*>` instead (or `std::observer_ptr` when it is implemented in the near future), as raw pointers (normally) imply non-ownership. You just have to be careful that the lifetime of the `std::vector<Edge*>` *doesn't* exceed the lifetime of the `std::unique_ptr`s, or else the pointers will be dangling.

Comment: *"std::vector::push_back copies its argument"*, there is an overload taking an rvalue reference which does not make any copy

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki True, I looked at the wrong snippet, sorry

Comment: @wfbarksdale I think you want `std::move(vector[i])`

Comment: thanks @Rakete1111 answer was staring me in the face!

Comment: Shouldn't your method prototype be `void inline AddEdge(std::unique_ptr<Edge>&& edge)` to leverage move semantic?

Comment: @A.Gille you don't need a rvalue reference for move semantics. Such a reference wouldn't change anything here.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It is because the compiler will wisely choose between copying or moving?

Comment: @A.Gille Not in this case. It's because I'm passing in a moved object,which is treated like a temporary. A temporary will use the move constructor instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Ok, so it means that in your case the object is moved twice. One time by the caller while passing the method parameter, and a second time when pushing to the vector?

Comment: @A.Gille jup. It's not the same object though technically, but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to push a copy of the **std::unique_ptr** into the vector. The vector is attempting to create a copy of the unique_ptr, which isn't allowed since it would defeat the purpose of unique ownership.

You should first consider which object owns which object, and only use **std::unique_ptr** if there is indeed a case for unique ownership.

There are a couple things you can do:

1. **std::move()** the pointer into the vector, which will cause the previous copy to become invalid (see: move semantics).
2. Use **std::shared_ptr** if you want multiple objects to hold copies of the pointer. Since it looks like you want to have multiple copies of the pointer, this is probably the direction you want to go.

Its probably worth while in your case to read up on **std::weak_ptr** since I think you may want objects to refer to one another, without creating circular references. Weak pointers work on shared_ptr's without actually incrementing the reference count, and are important in some cases where you want to make sure objects aren't hanging onto references too long and creating memory leaks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use *smart pointers* at all for this. I think the simplest route is to store all your *nodes* and *edges* as *values* in the main *vectors* and then use *raw pointers* to express their relationships.

You don't need *smart pointers* because the *vectors* manage the lifetime and destruction of your *nodes* and *edges* so nothing else needs to own them.

The **most important thing** to remember with this scheme is that you must **never** change the size of a *vector* after the data structure that uses pointers to its elements has been created.

The reason being that changing the size of a vector invalidates all the pointers (the objects may be moved to different memory locations).

So something like this:

```
class Edge
{
    class Node* a;
    class Node* b;
    double w;

public:
    Edge(Node* a, Node* b, double w): a(a), b(b), w(w) {}
};

class Node
{
private:
    double x, y, z;
    std::vector<Edge*> inEdges;

public:
    Node(double x, double y, double z): x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    void AddEdge(Edge* edge)
    {
        this->inEdges.push_back(edge);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node> nodes; // values, not pointers
    std::vector<Edge> edges;

    // NOTE: You MUST create ALL of the Nodes BEFORE
    // adding their pointers to the Edges and you must
    // create ALL the Edges BEFORE adding their pointers
    // to the Nodes because resizing the vectors will
    // INVALIDATE all the pointers

    // FIRST create ALL the nodes
    nodes.emplace_back(0, 0.5, 0.0); // make nodes[0]
    nodes.emplace_back(1, 0.5, 0.0); // make nodes[1]

    // NEXT create ALL the edges
    edges.emplace_back(&nodes[0], &nodes[1], 1.0); // make edges[0]

    // Finally add the edges to the nodes
    nodes[1].AddEdge(&edges[0]);

}
```